# How come Belgium and even Switzerland are atop of Holland on FifaRankings for WorldCup 2014?

Tags: football, ranking, fifa, world-cup

**Holland**

- **reached finals** at **WorldCup2010**;
- **qualified** to **Euro2012**;
- won the qualifying group for **WorldCup2014** with only **one** draw.

**Belgium**

- **missed** WorldCup2010
- **missed** Euro2012
- won the qualifying group for **WorldCup2014** with **two** draws.

**Switzerland**

- **3rd place in group** at WorldCup2010
- **missed** Euro2012
- won the qualifying group for **WorldCup2014** with **three** draws.

Still the rankings are:

```
1    Spain          1513    
2    Germany        1311    
3    Argentina      1266    
4    Colombia       1178    
5    Belgium        1175    
6    Uruguay        1164
7    Switzerland    1138    
8    Netherlands    1136
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but is strength of opposition taken into account in calculating rankings? If Belgium and Switzerland were in stronger qualifying groups that could explain it.

Comment: If you follow that rule, Uruguay is not even in WC yet.. and if it reach it (almost sure, seeing that it won 5-0 it first leg), it will be head of group... That is more strange...

Comment: Related link: [Are Switzerland really better than Italy? FIFA’s insane ranking system explained](http://eurosport.yahoo.com/blogs/pitchside-europe/switzerland-really-better-italy-fifa-insane-ranking-system-144405289.html)

Comment: Here's how the FIFA ranking works - http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2904/how-does-fifa-rank-national-teams/2909#2909

Comment: [Are Switzerland really better than Italy? FIFA’s insane ranking system explained](http://www.eurosport.co.uk/football/are-switzerland-really-better-than-italy-fifas-insane-ranking-system-explained_sto4717005/story.shtml) new working link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this [link](http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/procedureandschedule/menprocedure/index.html) show you how the points are calculated. I don't remember how well did Netherlands did in the Euro2012, But you have to take in consideration how difficult stage group in the qualy round was, and how it is meassured according to the table. Also, take in mind, that not all the teams plays the same amount of games. So maybe Netherlands didn't play too much lately???

Answer (score 4):

One key thing to keep in mind is that the FIFA ranking does not indicate how strong a team is but how well they have done.  As the [ranking procedure](http://www.fifa.com/worldranking/procedureandschedule/menprocedure/index.html) indicates, it only uses results of past games to give a score. Citing results from 2010 is also slightly misleading since those results are divided by 5 (20%), where results from 2013 are worth significantly more. Netherlands played a lot of games that were outside of the three bullet points you've mentioned. Those friendlies made all the difference.  FIFA shows all the games Netherlands have played [here](http://www.fifa.com/associations/association=ned/fixturesresults/gender=m/index.html).
You will see draws to Portugal, Estonia, Germany, Japan, Colombia, Italy.  Some of these were before the draw took place and ended up costing them a seed.

That being said...it was very close and could have changed even in the last 2 games of qualifying.